# G is matrix lie group such that there is $A\in G$, it is not written as $A=e^{X_1}....e^{X_m} $ for some $X_1,..X_m\in \mathfrak g$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

> Counterexample: G is matrix lie group such that there is $A\in G$ such that A can not be written as $A=e^{X_1}....e^{X_m} $ for some $X_1,..X_m\in \mathfrak g$ where $\mathfrak g $ is lie algebra of G.

I come across theorem which states following

G is connected  matrix lie group such that  $\forall A\in G$ such that A can  be written as $A=e^{X_1}....e^{X_m} $ for some $X_1,..X_m\in \mathfrak g$.

I think this will not true in case of disconnected lie group.

So I wanted a construct example.

Please Help me.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just take an infinite discrete group as your Lie group, say, ${\mathbb Z}< {\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact any Lie group $G$ that is not connected will do: For any $g \in G$, $X \in \mathfrak g$, $\gamma : [0, 1] \to G$, $$\gamma(t) = g \exp (t X)$$ is a path between $g$ and $g \exp X$, so for any $X_1, \ldots, X_n \in \mathfrak g$, induction gives that $\exp X_1 \cdots \exp X_m$ is in the identity component of $G$.

For a trivial example, take $G$ to be any nontrivial discrete group: Then $\mathfrak g = \{ 0 \}$, and so $\exp X_1 \cdots \exp X_m = e_G$.